# How to get android Telephony.java from GoogleSource website

Tags: android, provider

Would you like to let me know how to get the latest Telephony.java from Googlesource as I can only find out the old version from this link
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/f013e1afd1e68af5e3b868c26a653bbfb39538f8/core/java/android/provider/Telephony.java? Thanks for your great help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/android
Here you can get this file by github

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it is old and there is no telephony.java in base/core/java/android/provider/ directory. Thanks.

Comment: Or you can copy and paste it in a file. Use VIM or editplus's column edit function to remove the line number.